# Android WebView only works for API 28

Tags: android, webview, android-9.0-pie

I have stored a website locally in my `assets` folder (i.e. `HTML`, `CSS` and `Javascript` files). Using a `WebView`, I can display the website on any phone I tried with Android 9, emulated or hardware. But when the API is lower than 28, the `WebView` is blank (apparently because the Javascript does not load; the website needs Javascript to display anything). This is the code I use:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/website.html");

WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");

webView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "JSInterface");
```

What can be the error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by fixing an error in the JavaScript file; I had used "append" instead of "appendChild" somewhere, which was apparently not a problem for API 28+, but resulted in an error otherwise.